# AngularJS HTML 5 Input Range Output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My `input type="range"` outputs 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

My question is, how can I change the output to the following using AngularJS?

- 1: Terrible
- 2: Below average
- 3: Average
- 4: Above average
- 5: Excellent

Here's my code:

```
<label for=fader>How would you rate this site?</label>
<input type=range min=1 max=5 value=1 id=fader list=ratingsettings ng-model="rating">
<datalist id=ratingsettings>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</datalist>

<p>{{rating}}</p>
```

[Here's my Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9zfihxIV70QSPazdeVj7?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct approach is to use a map object in controller:

```
$scope.mapRating = {
    1: "Terrible",
    2: "Below average",
    3: "Average",
    4: "Above average",
    5: "Excellent"
};
```

and then in HTML use it like this:

```
<p>{{mapRating[rating]}}</p
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/MtsjS0fuOSUiWFuA3GeF?p=preview